# How to insert space between brand tag and menu items in bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to insert a space between brand tag and menu items in bootstrap navbar.

I have the following in my codeigniter view:

```
      <a class="brand"  href="#">COMPANY NAME</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" >
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>        
          <li ><?php echo anchor('login', 'Sign Up') ?></li>             
        </ul>
```

Can someone advise me?

Comment: Have you tried anything? A `<br />` or CSS margin perhaps?

Comment: I wasn't sure if there is a standard bootstrap way of doing it maybe by adding a class or if I should use standard CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
.nav-collapse {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

should do it, but it's hard to be sure without seeing the rest of the CSS.

Comment: Thank you, That seems better